# C# GetPrivateProfileString() returns empty value. Updated question

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I already read the related topics but none of them are working for me. I was using this method to read the content of an ini file since many years ago. However, now I can still write the ini file but, when I am trying to read, I get an empty string even if I set the default value.
The only difference that I can see is the update from W10 to W11. Same Net framework, visual studio version... Is there any update related to GetPrivateProfileString() method?

```
GetPrivateProfileString(SectionName, KeyName, DefaultValue, sData, sData.Length, INIPath);
```

Comment: What [return value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-getprivateprofilestring#return-value) are you getting from the method call?

Comment: empty string "  "

Comment: Please update the question to show the full method declaration (and implementation if not marked extern) of your method call. If it returns a string it doesn't match the expected signature: `static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string lpAppName, string lpKeyName, string lpDefault, byte[] lpszReturnBuffer, int nSize, string lpFileName)`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, you have three points to consider for your problem.

**First, use a stringbuilder class as an out parameter.**

```
[DllImport("kernel32")]
    private static extern int GetPrivateProfileString(string section, string key, string def, StringBuilder retVal, int size, string filePath);
```

**Second, Check the parameter of the file location both your IDE and code.**

If a file is existed somewhere on a 'conf' folder,
the code might be as following  :

```
public static string ReadValue (string file, string section, string key)
{
    StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(255);
    int ret = GetPrivateProfileString(section, key, null, temp, 255, GetFile(file));
    return temp.ToString();
}
private static string GetFile(string file)
{
    return Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "conf", file);
}
```

And watch a properties tab and check 'Copy to Output Directory':

[image: copy if newer]

**Finally, check a BOM(Byte Order Marker) existed in a file header.**

It's two heading bytes for special reason.

[Byte order mark-Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)

It looks normal on a text-mode in your editor,

[image]

but not on a hex mode, something wrong happened...

[image]

You may have to get rid of that bytes programmatically...